# How to handle space in value - Unix KSH script

Tags: bash, unix, websphere, ksh, ibmhttpserver

Any help on this will be great. Here is a script which uses a variable rootCerLabel in Props.txt to add a certificate in a keystore via a command but the command fails because variable **rootCerLabel**'s value has spaces in it, I am not sure how to handle space in a value. I have tried escaping it will back slashes as well, but no luck.

**Props.txt** 
rootCer="/services/EGcompanyInternalCA/ABC_EGcompany_G2_Root_CA.cer"
rootCerLabel=" 'ABC EGcompany G2 Root CA' "
IHS_HOME="/usr/IhsInstalldir"

**AddRootCA.sh**

#!/usr/bin/ksh

. Props.txt 
addRootCertificates(){ 
        echo "Adding root and intermidiate in keystore" 
        $IHS_HOME/bin/gskcapicmd -cert -add -file $rootCer -db $IHS_HOME/InteralSSL/key.kdb -stashed -label $rootCerLabel 
        echo "Added  root and intermidiate in keystore." 
}

**sh -x AddRootCA.sh**

+ rootCer=/services/EGcompanyInternalCA/ABC_EGcompany_G2_Root_CA.cer
+ rootCerLabel='ABC EGcompany Root CA'
+ IHS_HOME=/usr/IhsInstalldir
+ echo "Adding root and intermidiate in keystore" 
+ /usr/IhsInstalldir/bin/gskcapicmd -cert -add -file /services/EGcompanyInternalCA/ABC_EGcompany_G2_Root_CA.cer -db /usr/IhsInstalldir/InteralSSL/key.kdb -stashed -label 'ABC EGcompany Root CA'

**CTGSK3020W Invalid object: EGcompany**

-Command usage-
Object     Action       Description
------     ------       -----------
-locale                 Set the display lang

Comment: Read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matters where you do the quoting. You can put as many quotes  in `Props.txt` as you want, if you incorrectly quote in `AddRootCA.sh`, you will not get the required result.

Props.txt:

```
rootCer="/services/EGcompanyInternalCA/ABC_EGcompany_G2_Root_CA.cer"
rootCerLabel='ABC EGcompany G2 Root CA'
IHS_HOME="/usr/IhsInstalldir"
```

AddRootCA.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

. Props.txt
addRootCertificates(){
    echo "Adding root and intermediate in key-store"
    $IHS_HOME/bin/gskcapicmd -cert -add -file "$rootCer" -db "$IHS_HOME/InteralSSL/key.kdb" -stashed -label "$rootCerLabel"
    echo "Added root and intermediate in key-store."
}
```